# Hide div on certain pages using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to hide a div on more than one but not all pages of a site. The following solution hides it on one page but how can I add two or 3 particular pages?

Original answer here: [Hide div based on url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339235/hide-div-based-on-url)

```
<script language="text/javascript">
$(function(){
      if (window.location.pathname == "mywebsite/Videos.html") {
            $('#navleft').hide();
      } else {
            $('#navleft').show();
      }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: This would a perfect area you could use server-side scripting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just give an or condition

```
$(function(){
      if (window.location.pathname == "mywebsite/Videos.html"||window.location.pathname == "url2.html"||window.location.pathname == "url3.html") {
            $('#navleft').hide();
      } else {
            $('#navleft').show();
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use JavaScript for this. Instead, set a class on the `<html>` or `<body>` elements indicating the current page. So if you're on the index page, `<body class='index'>`. This way, you can use CSS to toggle the visibility of particular elements:

```css
/* Hide navigation on index and video pages */
body.index #navleft,
body.videos #navleft {
    display: none;
}
```

If you do wish to use JavaScript though, you have several options ranging from *very readable* to *very concise*. Towards the readable end of the spectrum is to simply store the various pathnames in an array, and perform a quick look-up:

You could go with something very basic and use an array:

```js
var pages = [ 
    "/videos.html",
    "/photos.html"
];

$( "#navleft" ).toggle(
    $.inArray( location.pathname, pages ) >= 0
);
```

The `$.fn.toggle` function accepts a boolean value, which we can produce by looking up the current `location.pathname` in an array of potential values and testing the returned index. If it's found, we return `true` and the item remains shown - otherwise it will be hidden.